# Chrome can't open Google websites

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

Periodically my Chrome installation will fail to open any Google websites (for example, trying to search on the address bar, which involves accessing google.com, Gmail, Google News, etc...)

However, if I switch to Incognito mode, all these websites open fine.

I have tried reinstalling Chrome, no luck. I have disabled all my Chrome extensions, as I know some extensions are used in Incognito and still no luck. I have of course used anti-virus websites as well.

Has anyone experienced an issue similar to this before?

I am using Windows 7.

Comment: Have you manually deleted the user profile directory after you backup said folder?  What error do you get exactly when this starts to happen?  Does IE load this file ( they share the same certificate store )?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your settings and check if your homepage is set to google. **IF** that doesn't work check you computer for worms, viruses and general malware, I suggest Microsoft defender. If you are using the latest version of Google chrome then try downgrading. Also consider checking your proxy (if any). Although if none of these work you should probably log on to another computer or network and contact **cough** Google support.

All the best,
Aymen